# Qt undefined reference to `vtable for Msnger'

Tags: c++, qt, vtable

I get this error

```
/.../mainwindow.o:-1: In function `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
/.../mainwindow.cpp:-1: Chyba:undefined reference to `vtable for Msnger'
```

and i dont understand why. Only problems i found causing this message are declaration without definition and i dont see any of theese in my code.

here is class Msnger
msnger.h:

```
#include <QObject>

class Msnger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Msnger() {};
    ~Msnger() {};
    void sendOn();
signals:
    void ton() {};
};
```

msnger.cpp:

```
#include "msnger.h"

void Msnger::sendOn()
{
    emit ton();
}
```

Msnger is supposed to send message to my Mainwindow

in constructor of mainWindow:

```
msn = new Msnger();
connect(msn, SIGNAL(ton()),this, SLOT(on()));
```

where msn is:

```
public: Msnger * msn
```

can you pls explain to me what's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: chyba is Czech word for error.

Comment: "chyba" is also a Polish word for "maybe" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that `moc` is not being run on your files, or its result is not getting linked.

The golden rules are:

1. Make sure the `Q_OBJECT` macro is present in the definition of all `QObject`-derived classes.
2. Make sure you declare your `QObject`-derived classes in your header files **only**.
3. Make sure all of your header files are listed in your .pro file in the `HEADERS=` list.
4. Run `qmake` every time you add `Q_OBJECT` to one of your classes or modify your `.pro` file.

---

Addendum:

```
signals:
    void ton() {};
```

**Do not** implement a signal. `moc` will implement it for you.

Comment: Great! THX qmake solved it. I felt like there is a problem and tried rebuild project with QT Creator. Next time I try qmake manually first.

Comment: There's the "Run qmake" entry in the Build menu.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your compiler.

Make sure that [Qt Meta compiler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/moc.html) is running for the header file where Msnger class is defined. And the resulting moc_* cpp file is compiled with your compiler.

PS. It's good when QObject inherited classes names start with 'Q' e.g. QMsnger

Comment: Where can I check if "the resulting moc_* cpp file is compiled with my compiler"? Only moc_ file generated in my project folder is moc_mainWindow.cpp. Is that correct or there should be moc_msnger.cpp too?