# Making custom QProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressbar

I'm getting the `undefined reference to vtable for CustomProgressBar'` error when trying to launch following code:
**customprogressbar.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMPROGRESSBAR_H
#define CUSTOMPROGRESSBAR_H
#include <QProgressBar>
#include "task.h"

class CustomProgressBar : public QProgressBar
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomProgressBar(DayTask, QWidget* parent = 0);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    DayTask task;
};

#endif // CUSTOMPROGRESSBAR_H
```

**customprogressbar.cpp**

```
#include "customprogressbar.h"
#include <QPainter>

CustomProgressBar::CustomProgressBar(DayTask task, QWidget* parent) :
    task{task},
    QProgressBar(parent)
{

}
//paintevent
```

What could cause the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to vtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable)

Comment: For further readers, this seems to be an issue becaus the `paintEvent` method is virtual and declared but not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe moc (meta object compiler) is not being run for your header?
Anyway, it's duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742466/qt-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-msnger)

Comment: yep, that was the problem.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. I realize you don't have the comment privilege yet, but it still stands.